# I want to loop over a dataframe containing urls using rvest in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

First i scrape a certain amount of urls from a website and collect them into a dataframe. However i want to loop over the urls which i collected into the dataframe. This is my code:

```
library(rvest)library(dplyr)
library(XLConnect)
##########GET URLS###################################################################################
urls <- read_html("http://www.klassiekshop.nl/labels/labels-a-e/brilliant-classics/?limit=all")

urls <- urls %>% 
  html_nodes(".product-name a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>%
  as.character()

url <- as.data.frame(urls)
as.character(url$urls)


#########EXTRACT URLS FROM DATAFRAME URLS############################################################
#########CREATE DATAFRAME############################################################################
EAN <- 0
price <- 0

df <- data.frame(EAN, price)

#########GET DATA####################################################################################
pricing_data <- for(i in urls){

site <-read_html(i)
print(i)
  stats <- data.frame(EAN =site %>% html_node("b") %>% html_text() ,
               price =site %>% html_node(".price") %>% html_text() ,
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 data <-rbind(df,stats)
}
```

When debugging the loop runs over the urls. However it doesn't collect the data. Does anyone know how to get the data from the site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're `rbind`ing `df` to `stats`... but you never change `df`... I think you want to change the last line of your code to:
`df <-rbind(df,stats)`